# How to call 2 windows forms in each other in C++?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, circular-dependency

I've been trying to convert a C# program with multiple forms to C++, but turned out that if I just include them in each other, the code would not compile.

I have tried to use forward declarations, but it only gave me issues with object creation.

I also tried to use `#indef`, but the program still doesn't compile and gives the same errors (c2065, c2061, and c2227 as result when I try to `Show()` a newly created form).

And I couldn't properly work with ParentForm due to the lack of brains (sadly, but true).

Here is a small part of the code that causes issues for me:

NewPasswordInput.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Encrypt.h" //class with functions
#include "AccessGranted.h"
namespace PassEncryptPlus {
    //...
    public ref class NewPassInput : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    private: String^ key;
    public:
        NewPassInput(String^ key)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this->key = key;
        }
    //...
    private: Encrypt *encrypt = new Encrypt(); 
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        //...
        String^ newpass1 = textBox1->Text;
        String^ str = encrypt->WritePass(newpass1); //generating a new key
        int i = Application::OpenForms->Count;
        AccessGranted^ accessGranted = new AccessGranted(str) //passing the key
        accessGranted->Show();
        Hide();
    }
}
```

AccessGranted.h

```
#pragma once
#include "AccessGranted.h"
namespace PassEncryptPlus {
    //...
    public ref class AccessGranted : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    private: String^ key;
    public:
        AccessGranted(String^ key)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this->key = key;
            richTextBox1->Text = key;
        }
    //...
    private: System::Void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs^  e) {
        NewPassInput^ newPassInput = gcnew NewPassInput(str);
        newPassInput->Show();
        Hide();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

PS: `AccessGranted` appears first called by the form I didn't list here, if the order is important.

Comment: This is **not** C++, It's C++/CLI.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Should be fine now.

Comment: Or could be C++/CX.  I consider C++/CLI and C++/CX to C++, as poorly named as JavaScript is to Java.  Not because any of those are bad languages, merely because the naming conflation causes confusion.  (The C fans are probably pointing a finger at C++ as I type this.)